# map/set iterator not dereferencable

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, boost, boost-propertytree

Greeting

I use `boost ptree` to get some information also put in some time.

```
typedef ptree MInfo;
```

In my application i use following style to `.put` or `.get` information into my `MInfo`.

```
a_info.put<WORD>(PathTree(SStatus)(fwDevice).str(), s_status->fwDevice);

WORD y = a_info.get<WORD>(PathTree(SStatus)(fwSensors)(S_SWITCH).str());
```

In my new method i use the same structure to put info on my ptree to get it later.

```
HRESULT SBase::getPortStatusEvent(AInfo &a_info, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...

    using namespace boost::property_tree;

    a_info.put<WORD>(PathTree(SEvent)(wPortType).str(), port_Status->wPortType);      //This Line Cause the Error!!
    a_info.put<WORD>(PathTree(SEvent)(wPortIndex).str(), port_Status->wPortIndex);    //This Line Cause the Error!!
    a_info.put<WORD>(PathTree(SEvent)(wPortStatus).str(), port_Status->wPortStatus);  //This Line Cause the Error!!

    ....

    return WFS_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get error in `a_info.put`.

Any Idea ?!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was mapping this part to actual string path.

```
PathTree(SEvent)(wPortType).str()
```

I made method to handle it by my own!